# Slightly different CSS card flip effect

Tags: css, transform

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUz2m/1/)

Basically, instead of just the basic `rotateY(180deg)` method, I'm trying to combine it with a `translateX` transform so that the card looks like it's actually being picked up from the right side (left when flipping back) and then being laid back down on the "table" in its new orientation.

As you can see in the Fiddle, it has the right general motion, but for some reason the two faces are not in sync. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I guess I'm just not spacial-geometrically incined XD

Any help sorting this animation out would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/zUz2m/3/)

The trick is that the background needs another transform origin:

```
#tcb {
    background:#030;
    transform:translateX(-100%) rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) rotateY(180deg);
    z-index:0;
    transform-origin:100% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 50%;
}
```

The reason is that the angle of rotation is reversed, so that you need to flip it around the other border. (So, the origin at 100%). And now that you have changed, that, you need to readjust the offset (the translateX value)

I needed also to move the transform-origin for the foreground from the div (where it was set both for foreground and background) to the foreground div.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that seems to work perfectly. I did try changing the origin, but not the translateX, so I figured I was making it worse XD Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm following this example to implement the card flip effect and found his code doesn't work in IE. It works in Chrome, Firefox, etc http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html - do you know why that is?